# Save wp content to reading list and print

Tags: php, wordpress, session, cart

Is it possible to make some sort of "shopping cart" just without the whole register/payment stuff?

This is my scenario:

I have a custom post type with my "products" and i want a button to save the "prod." for later and add to a print list.

Just like a shopping cart or "wish list".

So lets say i am browsing for stuff i want to read and print i can just click the ones i want and they will be stored in my session and can be displayed on a page.

Hope this gives any meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use user meta data to store the products on an array and use the info when you want to print it.

You should use [add_user_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta), [get_user_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) and [update_user_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta).

Comment: this method will only work for users who are logged in right ?

Comment: Yes, you need the users to be on the database so they have to be registered.